# Incompatible shapes in merge layers in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm using Keras to build a semantic segmentation model. The model is fully convolutional, so while I'm training on specific sized inputs i.e. `(224,224,3)`, when predicting, the model should be able to take any sized input, right? However, when I try to predict on an image of a different resolution, I get an error about mismatched shapes in my merge layers. Here is the error:

```
(1, 896, 1200, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "predict.py", line 60, in main
    n = base_model.predict(x)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1790, in predict
    verbose=verbose, steps=steps)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1299, in _predict_loop
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2357, in __call__
    **self.session_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 982, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1032, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1052, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [1,56,74,512] vs. [1,56,75,512]
     [[Node: add_1/add = Add[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](conv2d_3/Relu, block5_conv3/Relu)]]
     [[Node: conv2d_14/div/_813 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_157_conv2d_14/div", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'add_1/add', defined at:
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "predict.py", line 42, in <module>
    base_model = models.load_model('mod.h5', custom_objects={'loss':loss})
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 240, in load_model
    model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 314, in model_from_config
    return layer_module.deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 140, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2500, in from_config
    process_node(layer, node_data)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2459, in process_node
    layer(input_tensors, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 603, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/merge.py", line 146, in call
    return self._merge_function(inputs)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/merge.py", line 210, in _merge_function
    output += inputs[i]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 821, in binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 73, in add
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Add", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [1,56,74,512] vs. [1,56,75,512]
     [[Node: add_1/add = Add[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](conv2d_3/Relu, block5_conv3/Relu)]]
     [[Node: conv2d_14/div/_813 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_157_conv2d_14/div", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

My model architecture is the following: I use VGG16 and strip the top layer, and basically put layers in reverse order on top. I also have skip connections between the last convolutional layers of each block. Basically, I'm implementing [SegNet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.00561.pdf). I don't really understand why I'm getting `Incompatible shapes: [1,56,74,512] vs. [1,56,75,512]`. I understand that adding an extra connection on to a layer must change its dimensions, but why does Keras's padding not take care of this?

Here is also the code that builds my model:

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(None,None,3))

vgg = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(None, None,3))
# vgg.summary()

if vgg_train is False:
    # Freeze VGG layers
    for layer in vgg.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

l1_1 = Model.get_layer(vgg, 'block1_conv1')
l1_2 = Model.get_layer(vgg, 'block1_conv2')
l1_p = Model.get_layer(vgg, 'block1_pool')

l2_1 = Model.get_layer(vgg, 'block2_conv1')
l2_2 = Model.get_layer(vgg, 'block2_conv2')
l2_p = Model.get_layer(vgg, 'block2_pool')

l3_1 = Model.get_layer(vgg, 'block3_conv1')
l3_2 = Model.get_layer(vgg, 'block3_conv2')
l3_3 = Model.get_layer(vgg, 'block3_conv3')
l3_p = Model.get_layer(vgg, 'block3_pool')

l4_1 = Model.get_layer(vgg, 'block4_conv1')
l4_2 = Model.get_layer(vgg, 'block4_conv2')
l4_3 = Model.get_layer(vgg, 'block4_conv3')
l4_p = Model.get_layer(vgg, 'block4_pool')

l5_1 = Model.get_layer(vgg, 'block5_conv1')
l5_2 = Model.get_layer(vgg, 'block5_conv2')
l5_3 = Model.get_layer(vgg, 'block5_conv3')
l5_p = Model.get_layer(vgg, 'block5_pool')


#Encoder: Basically re-building VGG layer by layer, because Keras's concat only takes tensors, not layers
x = l1_1(input_tensor)
o1 = l1_2(x)
x = l1_p(o1)
x = l2_1(x)
o2 = l2_2(x)
x = l2_p(o2)
x = l3_1(x)
x = l3_2(x)
o3 = l3_3(x)
x = l3_p(o3)
x = l4_1(x)
x = l4_2(x)
o4 = l4_3(x)
x = l4_p(o4)
x = l5_1(x)
x = l5_2(x)
o5 = l5_3(x)
x = l5_p(o5)

#Decoder layers: VGG architecture in reverse with skip connections and dropout layers
#Block 1
up1 = UpSampling2D()(x)
conv1 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(up1)
conv1 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
conv1 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
conv1 = add([conv1,o5])
batch1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)


#Block 2
up2 = UpSampling2D()(batch1)

conv2 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(up2)
conv2 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
conv2 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
conv2 = add([conv2,o4])
batch2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)


#Block 3
up3 = UpSampling2D()(batch2)

conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(up3)
conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
conv3 = add([conv3,o3])
batch3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)

#Block 4
up4 = UpSampling2D()(batch3)
conv4 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(up4)
conv4 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4)
conv4 = add([conv4,o2])
batch4 = BatchNormalization()(conv4)

#Block 5
up5 = UpSampling2D()(batch4)
conv5 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(up5)
conv5 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5)
conv5 = add([conv5,o1])
batch5 = BatchNormalization()(conv5)

#Final prediction layer
soft5 = Conv2D(dims, kernel_size=8, strides=8, activation='softmax', padding='same')(batch5)


model = Model(input_tensor,soft5)
model.summary()

return model
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution in case anyone else runs into this issue. Merge layers need to have the same dimensionality, for obvious reasons. The problem arises when downsampling/upsampling. An image with a width of 115 for example, if downsampling by a factor of 2, will be reduced to the ceiling of 57.5, i.e 58. When upsampling this, the resulting tensor has width 116, which causes problems when trying to merge the 115 width layer with one of width 116. The solution for my case was pretty simple. Since all of my training data is the same size, the issue only occurs during inference. At this time, if the image has a dimension not divisible by 32, I just resize and then crop so that it does.